# Polymer paper-toast "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of null core-overlay.html"

Tags: events, polymer

I had this issue with paper-toast element on my local dev(but could not replicate it here on [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/689xkiqGJqgThuSqWWYL?p=preview))

Then I found solution that works for me, but could not tell why it works. Just placing that finding here, don't have questions:

when placed inside 'core-change' or 'change' listener paper-toast threw this error:

```
<script>

document.querySelector('.validation').addEventListener('core-change', function(e) {

    console.log('validation core-change');

    toast_element = document.getElementById('toast1');
    toast_element.text = 'toast_element msg';
    toast_element.show();
    //On local - this is the error:
    // ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of null core-overlay.html:574
    //solved with placing the code under setTimeout
    setTimeout(function()
        {
           //toast call here
           //toast_element = document.getElementById('toast1');
           //toast_element.text = 'toast_element msg';
           //toast_element.show();
        },500);

});
</script>

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of null core-overlay.html:574 Polymer.resetTargetDimensionscore-overlay.html:407 Polymer.transitionendcore-overlay.html:672 (anonymous function)polymer.concat.js:8391 b.firecore-transition.html:117 Polymer.completecore-transition-css.html:206 (anonymous function)core-transition.html:132 listener
```

I solved this by placing paper-toast.show() method under setTimeout.

Also noticing that:

if slider is taped to move to same point there is an error,

if slider is dragger there is NO error

Comment: Have you tried putting your script inside `domReady` callback?

Comment: Just did. I did put 'change' event insight 'polymer-ready' event 
( https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready ). Same error appears - if slider is taped to move to same point there is an error, if slider is dragger there is NO error.